# Jndi lookup finds non existing resource

Tags: java, jpa, jndi, apache-tomee

I have a java web application, running on tomee 1.7.1 web profile.

db-resource configuration:

```
<Resource id="Test_IS" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver  org.postgresql.Driver
    JdbcUrl     jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
    UserName    postgres
    Password    1   
    JtaManaged  true
</Resource>
```

persistence unit with **wrong** data source id:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence ...>
  <persistence-unit name="Test1_PU" transaction-type="JTA">
   <jta-data-source>AAABBB</jta-data-source>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I expect a *NamingException* by lookup, but

```
EntityManager entityManager = (EntityManager) InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/env/AAABBB");
```

returns me a EntityManager for wrong(!) data source.
In tomcat log I found:

```
Feb 05, 2015 1:22:08 PM org.apache.openejb.config.AutoConfig logAutoCreateResource
INFORMATION: Auto-creating a Resource with id 'Test_ISNonJta' of type 'DataSource for 'Test1_PU'.
```

Can I turn off this "feature"?

Comment: This might help you: http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/Disable-auto-create-resource-TomEE-1-5-1-td4660448.html

Comment: Thank you,  #tomee.autoconfig=false or #openejb.offline=true works